# Why am I getting below after running this code? terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

#Problem:
#Fibonacci number

#Code:

```
int fibrecursion(int num,vector<int>&store)

{

    if(store[num]!=0)return store[num];
    if(num==1||num==2)return 1;
    
    int ans=fibrecursion(num-1,store)+fibrecursion(num-2,store);
    ans=ans%(int(pow(10,9))+7);
    store[num]=ans;
    return ans;
}

int main() 

{

    int A;
    cin>>A;
    vector<int>store(A+1,0);
    store[1]=store[2]=1;
    return fibrecursion(A,store);
    
}
```

Comment: [Your code works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KA6HUZ4wUcwznzO6). What is your input?

Comment: You probably should make sure that A is  valid and at least 2. bad_alloc() will happen if A is negative

Comment: Could good ole' StackOverflow due to exploding recursion. What is the number A?

Comment: at a guess `A` is larger than the value representable in an `int` which gets converted to a large `size_t` value resulting in `bad_alloc` when creating the vector.

Comment: Side note: `int(pow(10,9))` has the potential to screw up when it converts the floating point output of `pow(10,9)` into an integer. Practically it shouldn't happen these days because a compiler should go, "Hummmm. always 10 to the 9. Think I'll replace that with a constant." But there's room for interpretations that result in the close-enough 999999999.999999999 being truncated to 999999999.

Comment: For which A does it fail?